# Second derivative of the logarithm of the modified Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: real-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, probability-distributions

This question makes sense entirely without the probabilistic perspective, but let us quickly describe how it arises in our setting. Let $X,X’$ denote two i.i.d. random variables having the distribution Poisson($\lambda$). Then the difference $Y:=X-X’$ has the modified Bessel function (of the first kind) as the probability density function. Write $p:\mathbb Z\to[0,\infty)$ for this function, the modified Bessel function (of the first kind), see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1).

Question: Is the second derivative of $-\log p$ non-increasing over $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ for any parameter $\lambda>0$?
The second derivative of a function $a:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb R$ is defined by
$$
a^{(2)}(x):=a(x+1)+a(x-1)-2a(x).
$$

The answer is yes if $\lambda$ is small, but a simple calculation does not suffice when $\lambda$ is large. If $-\log p$ is non-increasing then this implies a monotonicity property in certain particle systems which seems to be of physical relevance (a Fortuin-Kasteleyn-Ginibre inequality for the absolute value of a height function, to be precise). There is a workaround in any case, but an elementary proof of this inequality would be better.

Edit: For fixed $\lambda>0$, the function $p:\mathbb Z\to[0,\infty)$ is defined by:
$$
p(m)
=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\mathbb P(X=|m|+k)\mathbb P(X'=k)
=
e^{-2\lambda}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{\lambda^{|m|+2k}}{(|m|+k)!k!}.
$$

Comment: The Bessel function takes two arguments, so your description of $p$ is unclear. Can you write a precise formula for it in terms of $I_\alpha(z)$?

Comment: This is not true on the set $\{0,1\}$ if $\lambda$ is small enough. Do you want the monotonicity only on the set $\{1,2,\dots\}$?

Comment: Thanks, I've added an elementary definition of the function $p$.